# JSON Schema: require at least one non-positional array element

Tags: jsonschema

Hello fellow stackoverflowers!

I have a 'problem' with JSON schema code and validating JSON arrays. My problem is that I require at least one element in an array to adhere to a certain schema, but the remaining elements can be freeform. I cannot assume my searched element to be in a certain position of the array. Using integers only (for simplicity) the problem can be rephrased to: "write a schema that validates that there is at least one 1 in the array regardless of its position". Positive examples would be:

```
[1]
[0, 0, 1]
["a", true, null, 1, false, null, 3.2]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Negative examples would be:

```
[]
["a"]
[0, 2, 4]
```

Using the documentation at [json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html) (Draft 04) and playing around with the [JSON Schema Validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) I came up with my own solution which uses double negation and feels quite cumbersome:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "testid",
  "title": "test array schema",

  "not": {
    "items": 
      {
        "not": { "enum": [1] }
      }
  }
}
```

It uses the principle "not (for-all-items (not is 1))", which works but feels not very elegant. Is there something like a "require" for arrays that I missed?

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything.  You can specify a schema for all items, or you can specify a schema for each index.  That's all you have to work with.

There is a proposal for a [`contains`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/contains-(v5-proposal)) keyword for Draft 05, but progress on Draft 05 has been stalled for a while now.  The schema you have is the best you can do with Draft 04.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Jason! The link that you provided was really helpful. I did not find the proposal for Draft 05 when I was looking for the solution and, indeed, the proposed `contains`-keyword is what I was looking for.So the solution for getting a more the elegant schema using `contains` will be: waiting.

Comment: FWIW, `contains` exists now -- since April 2017 actually, added in draft 6 -- https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wright-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.14